# Is there a way to create a MAX_BY UDF in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, bigquery-udf

There are built in MAX_BY functions in other warehouses that take 2 arguments where the first is the column you want returned and the second argument is the value you want to maximize. I have been trying to write an efficient function to do just that to no avail.

My assumption would have it looking like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dataset.MAX_BY(col ANY TYPE, val ANY TYPE) RETURNS STRING AS
(SELECT col
FROM my_table
ORDER BY val DESC
LIMIT 1)
;
```

Issue being, I want the table inferred from the column/function or for the full columns to be passed through and sorted to select the correct value.
I don't know JS, so unsure if that would be a better option.

I have attempted a few different variations of trying to aggregate without a table.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value(return_value having max value_to_maximize)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

here I am taking max of year by earnings. I think this is what you wanted. let me know if this works?

```
Sample Query 1: This gives output year 2022

    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(year ORDER BY earnings DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] as maxByValue FROM (
    SELECT "2020" as year, "1000" as earnings 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021" as year, "2000" as earnings 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022" as year, "7000" as earnings 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "2023" as year, "4000" as earnings 
    )

Sample Query 2: This gives output year 2023

SELECT ARRAY_AGG(year ORDER BY earnings DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] as maxByValue FROM (
SELECT "2020" as year, "1000" as earnings 
UNION ALL
SELECT "2021" as year, "2000" as earnings 
UNION ALL
SELECT "2022" as year, "3000" as earnings 
UNION ALL
SELECT "2023" as year, "4000" as earnings 
)
```

Comment: That is what I want, but the trouble I am having is generalizing the input for a user defined function. I would like to be able to provide column 1 as year and column 2 as earnings to an aggregate function. Here is the documentation from presto I am trying to mimic:
`max_by(x, y) → [same as x]
- Returns the value of x associated with the maximum value of y over all input values.`